# Why is there a space between div tags when I put a h1 tag in a div tag?

Tags: html, css

This html code adds a space like in this image:

[image: Image of html page]

But, I don't want those spaces in between the divs,

And, when I remove the h1 tag, it removes the spaces

Can someone help me out here? Any help would be appreciated!

```css
.div {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-table;
  border-color: #91b8f7;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
  <p style="font-size: 25px;">RHT</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<!-- new row -->
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 34%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 21%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 45%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
  <h2 style="float: left; padding-left: 64%">
    TITLE
  </h2>
```

Comment: The code sample you provided is looks like slightly different from the image you uploaded.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't include an H1 tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline elements (the `divs` set to `display: inline-table`) are trying to lineup according to the text baseline.  The gaps are created because not all the text is the same font size.  Notice how the text lines up in this screen cap:

[image: screen grab]

Changing the `vertical-align` property to something like `top` will change how these inline elements are aligned.  That will remove the gaps, but I'm not sure why `inline-table` is being used.

```css
.div {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-table;
  border-color: #91b8f7;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
  <p style="font-size: 25px;">RHT</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<!-- new row -->
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 34%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 21%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 45%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
  <h2 style="float: left; padding-left: 64%">
    TITLE
  </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `display` attribute. One solution would be to use `h1 { display: inline }`.

```css
.div {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-table;
  border-color: #91b8f7;
}
h1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<!-- new row -->
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 34%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 21%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 45%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
  <h2 style="float: left; padding-left: 64%">
    TITLE
  </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

That gap is generated by the `p` tag that contains these letters: RHT because of it's font-size and margin. You can "fix" the problem by removing the font-size from that div or by giving a 0 margin to every single `p` tag in your code. Either way, i would rather use css grid-layout or flex-box to generate the code structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses `display: table-cell;` and `float: left;`. The h-tag isn't touched. Space between divs is removed.

```css
.div {
  border: 1px solid #91b8f7;
  display: table-cell;
  border-color: #91b8f7;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
  <p style="font-size: 25px;">RHT</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<!-- new row -->
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 34%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 21%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 45%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div style="display: block;">
  <h2 style="float: left; padding-left: 64%">
    TITLE
  </h2>
```